# Regex ignore word

Tags: regex, unix

I have this string:

```
[06/Aug/2016: 11:47:29 +0500] [cameroun.tn][/var/log][2] Warning. Match of "rx \\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css|ttf)$" against "REQUEST_FILENAME" required. [file "/var/log"] [line "29"] [td "90"] [msg "wel done"]
```

I'm using this regular expression to extract the date:

```
^\[[^][]*[+][0-9]{4}]
```

and message:

```
\[msg .*\]
```

How can I ignore all the words between the date and the message to get only them using a single match?

Comment: Maybe `^\[[^][]*[+][0-9]{4}](.*)\[msg` and grab Group 1 contents?

Comment: Use Capture Groups.

Comment: What is the expected output? What exact tool are you using? `grep`? With `grep`, you will need a PCRE regex like `grep -oP '(?<=^\[[^][]*[+][0-9]{4}]).*(?=\[msg)'`

Comment: is not working i have all the line in the output

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you want is:

```
^\[([^][]*\+\d{4})\].*\[(msg\s*"[^"]*"\s*)\]
```

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hK3aWV/1)

What it'll do is match and capture the date string, match the rest of the string, then match and capture the message. You can then extract the contents of the capture groups (I'm assuming you're doing this in `bash` from your question tags):

```
pattern='^\[([^][]*\+\d{4})\].*\[(msg\s*"[^"]*"\s*)\]'
if [[ $string =~ $pattern ]]
then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

Comment: thanks, can you please adapt this regexp ^[([^][]*\+\d{4})].*[(msg\s*"[^"]*"\s*)] with pyton  to compilr it with regxp python compilateur